# Conditional layout based on message content

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

Currently using `nglog` for my ASP.NET core application. How can I insert a new line for the associate log line whenever a '`~`' is at the beginning of the log message?

Currently I have the following:

```xml
 <variable name="DefaultLayout" value="${date}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${event-properties:item=callerName}|${event-properties:item=lineNumber}|${message}${onexception:|${onexception:${newline}${exception:format=tostring}}"/>
 <variable name="Main" value="${when:when=starts-with('${message}','~'):inner=${newline}${message}:else=${DefaultLayout}}"/>
```

I'm assuming it's with this condition, but I can't seem to get syntax correct.

```
${when:when=starts-with('${message}','~')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use for regex to replace strings by adding this line in NLog config

```xml
<variable name="Main" value="${replace:searchFor=^~:replaceWith=\n:regex=true:inner=${message}}" />
```